# Required request part 'uploadFile' is not present for SpringRestController with two parameters MockMvc

Tags: spring, rest, multipartform-data, mockmvc

i'am trying to test my Rest Controller which signature is :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/add", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
@RoleAdministrateur
public ResponseEntity<Object> addThing(@RequestParam("uploadFile") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("comment") String comment)
```

here is My moCkMvc test :

```
File fichier = new File(cheminFichier);

    MockMultipartFile part1 = new MockMultipartFile("uploadFile", file,  MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(fichier));
    byte[] json = "{\"comment\":param}".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    MockMultipartFile jsonPart = new MockMultipartFile("comment", "json", "application/json", json);
    resultat = mockMvc.perform(
            multipart(url)
                    .file(part1)
                    .file(jsonPart)
                    .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
```

but i have the following error message
Required request part 'uploadFile' is not present

http error code : 400
`

Comment: can you put a reproducer in github ?

Comment: the problem was that spring controller needed to know the parameter in yaml:Spring:servler:multipart:max-file-size:10MB; and this solved the problem